# Figuring out unicode: 'ascii' codec can't decode

Tags: python, unicode

I currently use Sublime 2 and run my python code there. 
When I try to run this code. I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   6: ordinal not in range(128)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
s = unicode('abcdefö') 
print s
```

I have been reading the python documentation on unicode and as far as I understand this should work, or is it the console that's not working

**Edit:** Using s = u'abcdefö' as a string produces almost the same result. The result I get is

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in
>   position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: A [Google search][1] of *'ascii' codec can't decode* returns 12,400 matches just for Stack Overflow... You might want to do a little research on this site first...


  [1]: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com%20%22%27ascii%27%20codec%20can%27t%20decode%22

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use the [latest](http://docs.python.org/) version of Python which doesn't have these problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens is that `unicode('abcdefö')` tries to decode the encoded string to unicode during *runtime*. The `coding: utf-8` line only tells Python that the *source file* is encoded in utf8. When the script runs it has been compiled and string has been stored as a *encoded string*. So when Python tries to decode the string it uses ascii by default. As the string is actually utf8 encoded this fails.

You can do `s = u'abcdefö'` which tells the compiler to decode the string with the encoding declared for the file and store it as unicode. `s = unicode('abcdefö', 'utf8')` or `s = 'abcdefö'.decode('utf8')` would do the same thing during runtime.

However does not necessarily mean that you can `print s` now. First the internal unicode string has to be encoded in a character set that the stdout (the console/editor/IDE) can actually display. Sadly often Python fails at figuring out the right character set and defaults to ascii again and you get an error when the string contains non-ascii characters. The Python Wiki knows [a few ways](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails) to set up stdout properly.

Comment: There was a presentation by Ned Batchelder at PyCon in which he discusses these and similar issues. It is available here - http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: When I try to use this string: s = u'abcdefö' it produces almost the same result. Namely this:  'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 6

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the string as a unicode string:

```
s = u'abcdefö'
```

Answer (score 0):

**s = 'abcdefö'**

DO NOT TRY unicode() if string is already in unicode. i.e. **unicode(s) is wrong**.

IF **type(s) == str** but contains unicode characters:

1. First convert to unicode

   ```
   str_val = unicode(s,'utf-8’)
   str_val = unicode(s,'utf-8’,’replace')
   ```
2. Finally encode to string

   ```
   str_val.encode('utf-8')
   ```

Now you can print:

print s